# Can't add Launch Image for Landscape in XCode5

Tags: ipad, ios7, xcode5

I added Lanch Image in my iOS Project with `XCode5`.

[image]

Here is problem ,When i added `Landscape Non-Retina` , the `Landscape Retina` image showing is disappearing.

So i added `Landscape Retina` again , above `Landscape Non-Retina` image showing is disappearing too.

Only one is working not both.

I don't know why i can't add both.
I need to add both image for `Retina and Non-Retina.`

How can i add it?